# Creating Multiple event callbacks from fragment to the activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I was able to create a single event callback from a fragment to the activity. However, I have problem with creating two event callbacks from the same fragment.
Basically, I have a button on the fragment1 layout, when click on it, it will execute something in mainactivity, and then, it changes hide the Button at fragment1 layout, and then  I need to send a Boolean from the fragment to activity, then initiate fragment2.

How can I implement the 2nd callback interface in the mainacativity.

Here is my code:
at Fragment1:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{

private static final String TAG = "Fragment1";

Boolean in1, in2;
Button btn1;

ListenerA mListenerA;

public interface ListenerA{
    public void methodA(Boolean in1);
};

ListenerB mListenerB;

public interface ListenerB{
    public void methodB(Boolean in2);
};

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    if(context instanceof ListenerA)
        mListenerA = (ListenerA)context;

    if(context instanceof ListenerB)
        mListenerB = (ListenerB)context;
}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

    btn1 = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.btn1_ID);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListenerA.methodA(true);
        }
    });     
    return myView;
}

public void showBtnMethod (Boolean showBtn){
    if (showBtn==false) {
        btn1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        mListenerB.methodB(true); //***** problematic line
    }
}
}
```

and the code in the main activity is below. please note that on the first line I was able only to implement one method from the fragment.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Fragment1.ListenerA {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
public Fragment1 mFragment1;
public Fragment2 mFragment2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction1 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        mFragment1 = new Fragment1();
        transaction1.replace(R.id.content_fragment_ID, mFragment1);
        transaction1.commit();
    }
}

// this gets called by ListenerA when click on the button
public void methodA(Boolean in){
    if (in==true){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "mMethodA Executed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        triggerShowMethod();
    }
};

private void triggerShowMethod(){
    mFragment1.showBtnMethod(false);
};
// Problematic section is below
public void methodB(Boolean in){
    if (in==true){

        FragmentTransaction transaction2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        mFragment2 = new Fragment2();
        transaction2.replace(R.id.content_fragment_ID, mFragment2);
        transaction2.commit();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "mMethodB Executed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
};

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply consolidate both interfaces into one:

```
public interface Listener{
    public void methodA(Boolean in1);
    public void methodB(Boolean in2);
};
```

and in your MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Fragment1.Listener
```

Comment: Hi Pooya, your solution works great for one fragment. However, if I have another Listener at Fragment2, how can I implement it in Mainactivity?

Answer (score 0):

Your activity doesn't implement ListenerB.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Fragment1.ListenerA, Fragment1.ListenerB {

}
```

Comment: Hi ElDuderino, I understand but not able to implement it. How can I do that?

Comment: The same way you implemented ListenerA. Add it on the activity.

Comment: can your write the first line of the code?    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements

Comment: public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Fragment1.ListenerA, Fragment1.ListenerB.

Comment: That's failed in Build  with 2 errors

:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: Hm, that looks like another problem, you should ask a new question about that. Did you run it with --stacktrace?